# ipad: Crash out of application is not generating an exception?

Tags: ios, ipad, exception, crash

I am having this horrible crash out of my application that I have been trying to resolve for several days now.  The code is an NSURLRequest to send a request to a web-service.  I already use the web-service in production and I simply added this new service request.  I finally added @try ... @catch around the offending code and it still crashes the application and does not "catch" anything.

How do I debug this?

I have used code inspection, including a peer review.

The code is like this ... where "httpClient" is an NSObject with:

```
id                      _delegateConnection;
id                      _delegateReceiver;
NSURLConnection         *connection;
NSMutableURLRequest     *urlServiceRequest;
NSMutableString         *bodyRequest;
NSHTTPURLResponse       *httpResponse;
NSMutableData           *responseData;
NSError                 *error;

@try {
    [httpClient setDelegateReceiver: self];
    [httpClient buildRequest: dictParameters];
    [httpClient executeRequest];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __FUNCTION__, exception);
}
@finally {
    // Add code here ...
}
```

Comment: Does the crash produce a crash report with an error type and a stack trace?  If you break on the first line inside your @try and step, which one does it die on?  (And is there code that can be stepped through inside the one that fails?)

Comment: No - it just exits.  It is inside my executeRequest method.  Good point -- I will update the code to try catch around the single offending line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it was through good-fortune and code inspection in a different part of the code ("where the light was better" :)

As it turns out, I have a dictionary of parameters that get written to a JSON string, added to the HTTP body of the `urlServiceRequest` object listed in my sample code.  What I finally stumbled upon was that the parameter container (NSObject, not NSDictionary) was not "`retained`", therefore it was probably "`autoreleased`", while still referenced within my `buildRequest` method, by the posting of the `urlServiceRequest`.

Poor memory management on my part led me astray in my troubleshooting.